# How to allow to choose the search field android

Tags: android

Is there a way to allow the user to select the field on which the search is performed?

When the user clicks on the search icon, I open the search widget and allow the user to enter text. Currently I use the text to search on 2 fields (name & region) but I would like to allow the user to select one of them.

I would like to have a drop down list with the field names that the user opens from within the search widget, maybe with a little arrow, as is done in Android Studio to show past strings of searches.

**Code**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    if (mSearchView != null) {
            TextView searchText = ((EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
            if (searchText != null) {
                searchText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                searchText.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            int r = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/close", null, getPackageName());
            if (r > 0)
                searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(r); //R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_normal);
            try {
                Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchPlate");
                searchField.setAccessible(true);
                LinearLayout searchPlate = (LinearLayout) searchField.get(mSearchView);
                if (searchPlate != null) {
                    searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.bgcolor));
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                MySingleton.printMyLog(0, "in MainActivity.SearchView.NoSuchFieldException [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                MySingleton.printMyLog(0, "in MainActivity.SearchView.IllegalAccessException [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
            }

            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
                    mSearchView.clearFocus();
                    mSearchView.setIconified(true);
                    mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                    mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
  // do my stuff
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I added the following code, in order to catch the click on the search icon, but the onClick() is not called

```
            mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 // my stuff - maybe to display a dialog box to ask the user the field to search on
                }
            });
```

Comment: Seems like what you need is [searchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Comment: I am using a searchView but I did not see that such option exists

Comment: Now you do :D you learn every day.

Comment: Can u be more specific - what is that option?

Comment: Well it's the android widget that might be perfect for your use-case. I've not personally used it, you can probably find many tutorial utilizing it online.

Comment: @Vucko, that was not very helpful

Comment: I am quite sorry that you think like that. I think I guided you in the right direction, you can surely take it on from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) or a library ([FakeSearchView](https://github.com/leonardoxh/FakeSearchView)) which will simplify it quite a lot.

Comment: I am using a searchView but I did not see that such option exists

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by opening a dialog when user clicks on the search icon inside onClick() of setOnSearchClickListener();